# What is the best practice to load and update data using Redis and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, redis, lumen

I am using Redis as caching layer and I'd like to know what is the best practice or how to use it properly alongside with DB (in this case MySQL).

Here I have an example of user dashboard function:

```
public function updateDashboardUser(Request $request) {

        $user = app('redis')->hGetAll($request->userID); //Get data from cache

        if ($user) { //if there is data use this

            $id = $user['id'];
            $name = $user['name'];

        } else { //otherwise use this
            $user = User::select('id', 'name')->where('id', '=', $request->userID)->first();

            $id = $user->id;
            $name = $user->name;

        }

        return response()->json(['id' => $id, 'name' => $name], 200);

    }
```

However this else statement is never reached somehow even though `$user` from cache might be empty. Is there a better way to do this?

Also while updating... Is there a better way to automatically update both (cache and DB) when data in one of them is changed.

```
public function editDashboard(Request $request) {
        $user = Route::find($request->userID);

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->save();

        $cacheEdit = app('redis')->hSet($user->id, 'name', $request->name);

        return response()->json(['status' => '200'], 200);
    }
```

At the moment I do it like this but sometimes only one of them might be changed and then cache data (or vice-versa, DB data) are not synchronized/updated.

This is my first experience with Redis and caching in general, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

- Instead of directly using Redis API, you should use Laravel cache API instead, it allows some abstraction and you don't even need to know which is the underlying cache.
- By using Eloquent instead of query builder, you may unlock some very powerful features such as model events. For example, in your `User` model:

```php
protected static function booted()
{
    parent::booted();

    $cache = app('cache');

    static::updated(function ($user) use ($cache) {
        $cacheKey = $user->getCacheKey();
        if ($cache->has($cacheKey) {
            $cache->put($cacheKey, $user, 30); //30 is the life duration of this value in cache, you're free to change it
        }
    });

    static::deleted(function ($user) use ($cache) {
        $cache->forget($user->getCacheKey());
    });
}

public function getCacheKey()
{
    return 'users.' . $this->getKey();
}
```

These "event hooks" get automatically called by Laravel whenever you update or delete a `User` by using Eloquent.

It allows you then to fluently do this:

```php
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as Cache;

public function updateDashboardUser(Request $request, Cache $cache, ResponseFactory $responseFactory)
{
    $id = $request->userID;

    $user = $cache->remember('users.' . $id, 30, function () use ($id) {
        return User::findOrFail($id);
    });

    return $responseFactory->json($user->only(['id', 'name']), 200);
}
```

Such as mentioned here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache , you can use `remember` (or `rememberForever`) to retrieve something from the cache and automatically fallback into a closure if not found. The `findOrFail` will then retrieves it from the database and will eventually throw an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` because it makes no sense then to send a successful response. I also replaced your helpers such as `response` by using dependency injection on contracts (Laravel interfaces) which is the cleanest practice.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/contracts

Comment: Actually I am using Lumen. Does this work for Lumen as well?

Comment: I don't know, I never used Lumen

Comment: @harunB10 said he is looking for best practices for "redis and mysql" - this answer says "Instead of directly using Redis API, you should use Laravel cache API instead". Laravel's cache methods are not even %1 of what redis can do. It is just a common interface supports basic operations(which are common for all drivers implementing that interface). It doesn't cover hash, list, set, sorted set, streams, hyperloglog which is what redis differentiates and has it's power on it.

Comment: @Ersoy yes but I want to use it in Laravel/Lumen, so Shizzen83 gave helpful answer.

Comment: @Ersoy Yes, and what he tries to do is actually a common operation, that's why abstraction is interesting. And notice that when I answered, the topic was mentioned as Laravel, not as Lumen

Comment: laravel/lumen doesn't make any difference on this - they are just two compatible tools which may use redis as dependency to execute all the operations. So if you want to apply it for "lumen" - it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In here it says too "The Lumen cache drivers utilize the exact same code as the full Laravel cache drivers. Beyond configuration, there are no differences between using the cache in Lumen and using the cache in Laravel; therefore, please consult the full Laravel documentation for usage examples." https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache